# jQuery: 100% height iframe in Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, iframe, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a php script that generates a document to print. I'm trying to get this script into a bootstrap 4 modal in 100% width and height so the client can check the content and then print it out.

```
<button type="button" id="print_modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#printmodal">Result</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="printmodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:210mm !important">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-1" id="print_btn">Tisk</button>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-left" id="print_content">
            <!-- IFRAME HERE -->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I first put the iframe into the modal, when is populated (for performance reasoning - sometimes it's a really long document) - this is working

```
$('#print_modal').click(function () {
  $('#print_content').html('<iframe src="./index.php?print" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="print_frame"></iframe>');
});
```

Than I need set 100% height on iframe element. The problem is that following jquery script returning 0 height. Probably because is hidden in modal by default.

```
$("#print_frame").on("load", function () {
  $(this).height($(this).contents().find("html").height());
});
```

I need something like timeout to check height of iframe after its populated, but I dont know how.

**Not working :**

Use onload parametr on generated iframe: ( return 0px - modal FadeIn is probably slower then iframe append ...)

```
<iframe src="./index.php?print" onload="ifrhgh()">

function ifrhgh(){
   var iframehght =  $("#print_frame").contents().height();
}
```

Comment: The two code snippets are identical

Comment: Sorry.... fixed

Comment: Try `$(this).contents().height()`

Comment: If the modal, which is the container here, is hidden when you attempt to measure it, the height will be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
The key is create iframe on **`shown.bs.modal`** (BS4 event triggered by modal after success load) Then onload parametr calling `ifrhgh()` function which set iframe equal to content

```
$(function () {
    $('#printmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#print_content').html('<iframe width="100%" onload="ifrhgh()" src="./index.php?print" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="print_frame"></iframe>');
    });
});

function ifrhgh(){
    var iframehght =  $("#print_frame").contents().height();
    $("#print_frame").height(iframehght);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part here is triggered from the button which also displays the modal. So the modal is supposed to be opened before the iframe loads.

```
$('#print_modal').click(function () {
  $('#print_content').html('<iframe src="./index.php?print" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="print_frame"></iframe>');
});
```

So that's ok.

But now, about the second part, the selector `#print_frame` does not exist on "page load", where I suppose this handler is defined. And that's a problem that can be fixed using [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Try this:

```
$(document).on("load","#print_frame",function(){
  var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().height();
  console.log(iframeHeight);  // Check the console for that value.

  $(this).height(iframeHeight);
});
```

Comment: No luck.This work only for dynamically divs,spans..etc and only with "click" trigger. With iframe isnt working even with "click"

Answer (score 0):

```js
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: none; 
}

.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
  height: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none; 
}

.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="print_modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#printmodal">Result</button>

<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen" id="printmodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-1">Tisk</button>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-left">

            <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%" src="https://example.com" ></iframe>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example Codesanbox](https://x8yrsg.csb.app/)

[Source](https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/full-screen-modal-bootstrap.html)